# iOS Navigation Bar background color

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am new to iOS development, I facing a strange problem. In **viewDidLoad**

I had written a code like this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:189.0/255.0 green:105.0/255 blue:105.0/255 alpha:1.0];
```

this is working fine and changed the navigation bar background color, the problem is in the top of the navigation bar there is white bar showing (that has Carrier, Battery, time), I want that background color also changed... so I tried the below code

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:189.0/255.0 green:105.0/255 blue:105.0/255 alpha:1.0]];
```

But nothing changed, it is showing same white background color, I would like to know whats the mistake I am doing

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:color]

Comment: No it is not working already I had tried that..

Comment: It works, you must ensure you set your appearance proxy before you load view controllers, e.g. in your app delegate applicationDidFinishLaunching method

Comment: In AppDelegate I had given like this - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:189.0/255.0 green:105.0/255 blue:105.0/255 alpha:1.0]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:189.0/255.0 green:105.0/255 blue:105.0/255 alpha:1.0]];

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this,

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

or

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

and

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `barTintColor` property in order to change the navigation bar background color and also the status bar background color.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:189.0/255.0 green:105.0/255 blue:105.0/255 alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: I tried Nikos but still the top bar (Carrier, Time, battery) is showing in white color, it is not showing as I wanted.